# Search query through all collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-realm, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm using mongodb Realm functions and want to run this query for all my collections in the database. I have to write a collection name; otherwise, I get this error:

```
'(AtlasError) Pipeline can only have no collection if the first stage is $changeStream', error_code: 'MongoDBError'
```

here is my code:

```
exports = function (payload) {
  const movies = context.services
    .get('mongodb-atlas')
    .db('subsDB')
    .collection('subtitles');

  let arg = payload.query.arg;
  let found=movies.aggregate([
    {
      $search: {
        index: 'default',
        text: {
          query: arg,
          path: {
            wildcard: '*',
          },
        },
      },
    },
   
  ]);
```

How can I run this query on all collections in my database?

Answer (score 0):

Use `db.getCollectionNames`:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collname) {
    c=db[collname].aggregate(yourPipeline);
});
```